# Word 2016: Open Initial Zoom Display Side-by-Side

Tags: default, zooming

Word-2016: I use the following VBA (module in Normal.dotm) to open all docs with an initial zoom of at 76%. Can I replace the 76 with something that will open with zoom displaying two pages side by side at 76%?

```
Sub AutoOpen()
  ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Zoom.Percentage = 76
End Sub
```